# Drawing a vector from transformed origin with tikzpicture and pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to draw a vector in Latex using *tikzpicture* and *pgfsplot* in my beamer presentation. Unfortunately, I don't get the desired output. The following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis} % Use metropolis theme
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
        \vspace{-0.5cm}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-6.067, xmax=6.433,
        ymin=-1.3,ymax=2.2,
        scatter/classes={a={mark=o,draw=black}},
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        scale=0.9
        ]

        \addplot[scatter,only marks,mark size = 1pt,fill = red,scatter src=explicit symbolic]
        table {
              % some points go here...
        };

        \end{axis}
        \draw[|->, black](0,0) -- (3,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
   \end{document}
```

produces the following output:
[image]
However, this is not what I want. What I would like to have is a vector from the origin (0,0) to the point (3,1) while keeping the limits of my axes as they are.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `\draw[|->, black](axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:3,1);` or even easier, add `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` to your preamble.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved my problem. However, it has to be noted that your statement has to be within the \begin{axis]... \end{axis} scope as I ended up with errors outside of this scope. A small follow-up question: How would I go about extending the vector such that it extends from one axis to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis} % Use metropolis theme
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-6.067, xmax=6.433,
        ymin=-1.3,ymax=2.2,
        scatter/classes={a={mark=o,draw=black}},
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        scale=0.9
        ]
        \addplot[scatter,only marks,mark size = 1pt,fill = red,scatter src=explicit symbolic]
        coordinates { (-6,1) (0,2) (6,1)
              % some points go here...
        };
       \addplot [|->, thick,  black]
        coordinates { (0,0) (3,1)};
        \end{axis}
       \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```